# How to do regex to match a number and then multiply the number at the same time for a large list in R?

Tags: r, etl

I have some data for example `c("1k", "2k", "1.5k" ...)`, and would like tp transform the ks to `c("1000", "2000", "1500", ...)`, gsub is quite fast in replacing a large list, but it wouldn't be able to match the `1` or `1.5` and then multiply `1000`.

I could match `(\d+(.\d{1})?[Kk])`, `(\d+(.\d{2})?[Kk])`, `(\d+(.\d{3})?[Kk])` and replace them, but it looks like a brute force approach so I would like to see is there any other ways I can quickly extra the number and then do the calculation?

I tried extracted the number and then multiplied them and then loop through the list and did a gsub individually but it is very slow.

Thanks a lot.

Note that the strings can be `'   1k'`, `'display price: 1k'`, `'1k - 2k'` and some other random characters etc. We always want to get the first price appears so for the `1k - 2k` case we want to get `1k`.
And also there are millions of rows so performance could gets worse when the substitution is being done several times.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159114/converting-unit-abbreviations-to-numbers

Comment: How would one convert "1k - 2k"? What is the expected output in that case?

Comment: @jdobres so if there is `1k - 2k`, we want to just get the first one which is `1k`

Comment: Hi @thelatemail, thanks for pointing out, it is similar but with slight differences, here the price will come with some random characters before and after the price number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the random characters this first removes all characters except digits, dot, k and K and then replaces k or K and everything thereafter with e3.  Finally it converts what is left to numeric.

```
x <- c("1k", "2k", "1.5k", "   6K", "1k - 2k")
as.numeric(sub("k.*", "e3", gsub("[^0-9.kK]", "", x), ignore.case = TRUE))
## [1] 1000 2000 1500 6000 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

We create a named `vector`, extract the numeric part and multiply with replaced non-numeric part

```
unname(as.numeric(gsub("[A-Za-z]+", "", v1)) *
     setNames(c(1e3, 1e6), c('k', 'm'))[sub("[0-9.]+", "", v1)])
#[1]    1000    2000    1500 1700000
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("1k", "2k", "1.5k", '1.7m')
```

Comment: Hi akrun, thanks for the advice, sorry I forgot to mentioned that the original prices will have some random characters as well. I think this will work well if there are no other random characters around the price, unfortunately because of the quality of the data, it contains some other random characters as well.

Comment: Hi akrun, sorry I put some more examples to it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
x = c("1k", "2k", "1.5k", "1k - 2k", "1m", "display price: 1k")
as.numeric(sub(".*(\\d+)k.*", "\\1", x)) * 1000
#[1] 1000 2000 5000 2000   NA 1000
#Warning message:
#NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Hi @d.b, thanks for the advice, I tried it and it worked in most of the cases but not work in cases like `'display price: 1k'`, is there ways to resolve the random characters before and after the price? Thanks

Comment: Hi @d.b, thanks for this. I copied those two lines but it gives me the wrong answer `1000 2000 5000 2000   NA 1000`