# Convert a factor column with numbers in k format into numeric without losing any data

Tags: r

I have a factor column which has numbers in it. Some numbers are written in k format, for ex. 99k, 9.25k, 91.9k, etc. while others are written in whole like 998, 575, etc. Two things I want to do-:

- I want to multiply the numbers having k by 1000 and remove the k.
- I want to convert this column into a numeric column without losing any data.

If I first convert it into numeric applying as.numeric, the k format numbers will become NAs.

I can't think of anything to resolve this. Can anyone help me with a solution in r?

Following is the Sample data

```
df=data.frame(
ID = c(1:8),
Likes = c('99k', '997','15.5k', '9.25k','575', '800', '8.5k', '2,400')
)
```

**EDIT** I still don't know what is the problem. After trying all the solutions present here, still NAs getting produced. I am providing the link for full data. Kindly go through it and help me to find the problem. The column I am concerned with is 'Likes'.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tR0F4SwGmsVjh5NGGpONP6LTaqgDOM4l/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting unit abbreviations to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159114/converting-unit-abbreviations-to-numbers)

Comment: You have commas in the numbers that need to be removed. See my edit in the line where I define `x_str`. I added a `gsub()` to remove the commas. As a debugging tip, filter the original dataset to where the `NA` values occur and you can spot things like this fairly quickly.

Comment: Will remember it in future!! Thanks a lot for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First detect which records with a "k".

```
df$is_k <- grepl("k", df$Likes)
```

Strip the "k", and then convert to numeric. If the record had a "k" then multiple my 1000, else multiple by 1.

```
df$Likes_num <- as.numeric(gsub("k", "", df$Likes)) * ifelse(df$is_k, 1000, 1)
```

---

### Edit

For multiple units, I adapted something I had elsewhere for a more complex problem. This shows the steps and is simple enough, though I am not sure how robust it is.

#### Function

```r
convert_units <- function(x) {
  
  if (class(x) == "numeric") return(x)
  
  # named vector of scalings (you can add to this)
  unit_scale <- c("k" = 1e3, "m" = 1e6)
  
  # clean up some potential nuisances with the input
  x_str <- gsub(",", "", trimws(tolower(as.character(x))))
  
  # extract out the letters
  unit_char <- gsub("[^a-z]", "", x_str)
  
  # extract out the numbers and convert to numeric
  x_num <- as.numeric(gsub("[a-z]", "", x_str), "", x_str)
  
  # develop a vector of multipliers
  multiplier <- unit_scale[match(unit_char, names(unit_scale))]
  multiplier[is.na(multiplier)] <- 1
  
  # multiply
  x_num * multiplier
}
```

#### Application

```r
df$Likes2 <- convert_units(df$Likes)
```

#### Sample Result

```r
  ID Likes Likes2
1  1   99k  99000
2  2   997    997
3  3 15.5k  15500
4  4 9.25k   9250
5  5   575    575
6  6   800    800
7  7  8.5k   8500
8  8 2,400   2400
```

Comment: Still NAs are being introduced. I guess I have both capital and small 'k' in the dataset. Can you modify the above code with respect to that?

Comment: Good idea!! One thing I just found out that my dataset has 'M's too. Can you include 'M' in the above code? Thanks

Comment: Does the link @camille provided in the comment help?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative, converting the numbers with ks into scientific notation:

```
df$Likes_num = as.numeric(gsub("k", "e3", df$Likes))
df
  ID Likes Likes_num
1  1   99k     99000
2  2   997       997
3  3 15.5k     15500
4  4 9.25k      9250
5  5   575       575
6  6   800       800
7  7  8.5k      8500
```

**Edited to cover entire dataset:**

So you have upper case Ks, as in 16.1K, upper case Ms, as in 1.2M, and also commas, as in 4,225. The following code takes care of all of these:

```
df$Likes_num = df$Likes
df$Likes_num = gsub(",", "", df$Likes_num)
df$Likes_num = gsub("K", "e3", df$Likes_num)
df$Likes_num = gsub("M", "e6", df$Likes_num)
df$Likes_num = as.numeric(df$Likes_num)

sum(is.na(df$Likes_num))
## [1] 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This way assumes that the values with `"k"` will become `NA` when changed to numeric, then change those values.

```
df$LikesNum <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(as.character(df$Likes)))
df$LikesNum[is.na(df$LikesNum)] <- 1000*as.numeric(as.character(sub("k$", "", df$Likes[is.na(df$LikesNum)])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's with `dplyr` and `stringr`

```
df %>%
 mutate(Likes_numeric = str_remove(Likes, "k|K"),
        Likes_numeric = as.numeric(Likes_numeric),
        Likes_numeric = ifelse(str_detect(Likes, "k|K"), Likes_numeric * 1000, Likes_numeric))

  ID Likes Likes_numeric
1  1   99k         99000
2  2   997           997
3  3 15.5k         15500
4  4 9.25k          9250
5  5   575           575
6  6   800           800
7  7  8.5k          8500
```

Comment: Can you post your data using ‘dput(YOURDATA)’ instead of the sample you posted?

Comment: And adjusted it for upper case/lower case

Comment: dput is producing too large data to be posted here unless there are some modifications which I don't know of.

Comment: Try ‘dput(head(YOURDATA))’

Answer (score 0):

I looked into your data, finding that you are using `K` rather than `k`. For general purpose, I guess you can try the following code, which is case insensitive for replacement

```
df <- within(df,Likes <- as.numeric(gsub("k", "e3", Likes,ignore.case = TRUE)))
```