# Hard to clean up salary data properly (NAs are generated)

Tags: r, if-statement, case, data-cleaning, na

I am trying to clean up the salary columns of the tibble below:

| min_salary | max_salary |
| --- | --- |
| 65K | 75K |
| 65K | 75K |
| 65K | 75K |
| 56.3K | 90.8K |
| 61.7K | 105K |
| 45,360 | 84,240 |

I do not know how to make the above two salary columns in the way that there are only numbers(no punctuation, no "K" character).

I tried 3 different ways. The result was the same in all those three cases.

**1)**

```
    yearly %>%
        mutate(min_salary = case_when(grepl("K", min_salary) ~ 
        as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", min_salary)) * 1000, TRUE ~ 
        as.numeric(min_salary)), 
        max_salary = case_when( grepl("K", max_salary) ~ 
        as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", max_salary)) * 1000, TRUE ~ 
        as.numeric(max_salary)
        )
         )
```

**2)**

```
    yearly %>%
        mutate( min_salary = ifelse(grepl("K", min_salary), 
        as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", min_salary)) * 1000, 
        as.numeric(min_salary)),
        max_salary = ifelse(grepl("K", max_salary), as.numeric(gsub(" 
        [^0-9.]", "", max_salary)) * 1000, as.numeric(max_salary)))
```

**3)**

```
yearly %>%
    mutate(min_salary = ifelse(str_detect(min_salary, "K"),
    as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", min_salary)) * 1000,
    as.numeric(min_salary)),
    max_salary = ifelse(str_detect(max_salary, "K"),
    as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]", "", max_salary)) * 1000,
    as.numeric(max_salary)))
```

**Result**

A tibble:

| min_salary | max_salary |
| --- | --- |
| 65000 | 75000 |
| 65000 | 75000 |
| 65000 | 75000 |
| 56300 | 90800 |
| 61700 | 105000 |
| NA | NA |

> ℹ 1,776 more rows
> ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
> Warning message:
> There were 2 warnings in `mutate()`.
> The first warning was:
> ℹ In argument: `min_salary = ifelse(...)`.
> Caused by warning in `ifelse()`:
> ! NAs introduced by coercion
> ℹ Run dplyr::last_dplyr_warnings() to see the 1 remaining warning.

How can I not generate "NA"? NA rows are those where there was no "K" in the original tibble.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159114/converting-unit-abbreviations-to-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can make a quick helper function then apply it across columns. I'm adding in both `tidyverse` and base R options:

Example data

```
yearly <- read.table(text = "min_salary max_salary
65K 75K
65K 75K
65K 75K
56.3K   90.8K
61.7K   105K
45,360  84,240", header = TRUE)
```

Code:

```
# tidy verse approach
quickfun <- function(x){
  yy <- readr::parse_number(x)
  ifelse(stringr::str_detect(x, "K"), yy*1e3, yy)
}

# in base R
quickfun_base <- function(x){
  yy <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", x))
  ifelse(grepl("K", x), yy*1e3, yy)
}
```

Applying it in your `dplyr`/`magrittr` chain:

```
yearly %>%
  mutate(across(c(min_salary, max_salary), ~quickfun(.x)))

#  min_salary max_salary
# 1      65000      75000
# 2      65000      75000
# 3      65000      75000
# 4      56300      90800
# 5      61700     105000
# 6      45360      84240
```

In base R using `lapply`

```
yearly[c("min_salary","max_salary")] <- lapply(yearly[c("min_salary","max_salary")], quickfun)

#  min_salary max_salary
# 1      65000      75000
# 2      65000      75000
# 3      65000      75000
# 4      56300      90800
# 5      61700     105000
# 6      45360      84240
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Your codes worked! I am not familiar with lambda functions yet. So, I need to study them to apply this method to other cases. I learned a lot from your answers. I appreciate your time and energy.

Comment: Great! If this sufficiently answers your question and no better answers arise, please mark it as answers to help clean up the site and let others know it's been answered. Glad it helped!